# Accessing a DLL with a header file in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, dll, header, codeblocks

I'm having trouble here. I don't know how to link and define methods in a C++ DLL inside a header file. How do I link it into Code::Blocks? Also, how do I define the method inside a header file? I know this seems like a stupid question but I can't find it anywhere online.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding, or do you mean `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` sort of thing.

Comment: I don't know. I want to be able to load the DLL, I don't know how to do that inside a header with MinGW.

Comment: Do you know how to do it outside of a header or without MinGW?

Comment: Nope. But this is how I want to learn it.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? Take a function in an existing DLL and wrap it in a function in your header?

Comment: Yeah. I want to keep my main.cpp clean.

Comment: Or you mean, accessing DLL functions into your .exe? If you think that's your case, try [this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL) :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean Windows because of the MinGW, it's not that bad. For example, a function in "theDLL.dll" named "someDllFunction" that takes a `double` and returns an `int` might have this excerpt:

```
//dllfunctions.h
int someDllFoo(double d) {
    auto dll = LoadLibraryW(L"theDLL");
    if (!dll) {
        //error
    }

    using FooType = int(*)(double);
    auto func = (FooType)GetProcAddress(dll, "someDllFunction");
    if (!func) {
        //error
    }

    int result = func(d);

    if (!FreeLibrary(dll)) {
        //error
    }

    return result;
}

//whatever.cpp
#include "dllfunctions.h"

int main() {
    int result = someDllFoo(3.2);
}
```

You could take this even further by writing a more generic caller. The following will not work for a void return type, since it assigns the result, but that's addable:

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
Ret callDllFunction(const std::wstring &dllName, const std::string &funcName, Args... args) {
    auto dll = LoadLibraryW(dllName.c_str());
    if (!dll) {
        //error
    }

    using FuncType = Ret(*)(Args...);
    auto func = (FuncType)GetProcAddress(dll, funcName.c_str());
    if (!func) {
        //error
    }

    Ret result = func(args...);

    if (!FreeLibrary(dll)) {
        //error
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    //tested example
    callDllFunction<int>(L"user32", "MessageBoxW", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
}
```

That *should* work, or at least be on the right track. Of course, as I said, that doesn't work for void return types until you add another version of it. You could also extend it for __stdcall functions. As well, it would be a good idea to set up an error mechanism so that the function from the DLL's errors can be handled. If it's something that uses `SetLastError`, it might be overridden by the `FreeLibrary` call. It really depends on what exactly you need it to do. You might also consider putting `dll` into a smart pointer that calls `FreeLibrary` when the function ends.